# tikz-uml: How to place a UML object below one's lane?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} % For graphics
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,calc,positioning,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

Diagram below:

\small\begin{tikzpicture} 

  \begin{umlseqdiag} 
    \umlactor{User} 
    \umlobject{Proxy} 
    \umlobject[x=7]{Entry station}
    \umlobject[x=10]{Dst station}  

    \begin{umlcall}[op=retrieve(token),return=pkt-info]{User}{Proxy}
      \begin{umlcall}[op=RReq,return=success]{Proxy}{Entry station}
      \end{umlcall}
      \begin{umlcall}[op=RReq,return=success]{Entry station}{Dst station}
      \end{umlcall}
      \begin{umlcallself}[op=lookup,return=pkt-info]{Dst station} 
      \end{umlcallself}
      \begin{umlcall}[op=RRes,return=success]{Dst station}{Entry station}
      \end{umlcall}
      \begin{umlcall}[op=RRes,return=success]{Entry station}{Proxy}
      \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlcall}

    \begin{umlfragment}[type=loop, label=$\forall p_k$, inner ysep=1]
      \begin{umlcall}[dt=7, op=retrieve(token $p_k$),return=fragment $p_k$]{User}{Proxy}
        \umlcreatecall[x=7]{Proxy}{Station}
        \begin{umlcall}[op=RRes,return=success]{Proxy}{Station}
        \end{umlcall}
      \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlfragment}

    \begin{umlcallself}[dt=5, op=aggregate($p_k$), return=packet $p$]{User} 
    \end{umlcallself}
  \end{umlseqdiag} 

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Which emits the following:[image]

The problem is on object `Station`. I actually don't want to have the create call. I would just like that lane to be placed there for object `Station` and use it, that's it. I do not want the `create` call to happen.

If not possible, how can I at least change the label so that instead of showing `create` it shows something else?

Comment: As others already recommended on some of your previous questions, please provide a complete minimal example and not just a code fragment.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Done :)

Comment: To remove "create" you could use the (same) color of the background: `\umlcreatecall[x=7,text=white]{Proxy}{Station}`. I don't know another way.

Answer (score 1):

The text of that node is written directly in the code of the package (line 4622, in the latest version), it is not represented by some macro that can be redefined.

You can however, with the help of `xpatch`, patch the definition of `\umlcreatecall` to replace `{create}` with e.g. `{\CreateTxt}`, a macro that you can define and redefine as you like. Below I initially defined it as `\newcommand{\CreateTxt}{create}`, and redefined it with `\renewcommand` in the diagram.

Unrelated note: you load `graphicx` twice, which isn't really necessary. And both `graphicx` and `xcolor` are loaded by `tikz`, so adding them explicitly isn't strictly necessary. `tikz` in turn is loaded by both `pgfplots` and `tikz-uml`, so with one those present .. you get the point.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand\CreateTxt{create}
% in the macro \umlcreatecall, replace "{create}" with "{\CreateTxt}":
\xpatchcmd{\umlcreatecall}{{create}}{{\CreateTxt}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\small

  \begin{umlseqdiag} 
    \umlactor{User} 
    \umlobject{Proxy} 
    \umlobject[x=7]{Entry station}
    \umlobject[x=10]{Dst station}  

    \begin{umlcall}[op=retrieve(token),return=pkt-info]{User}{Proxy}
      \begin{umlcall}[op=RReq,return=success]{Proxy}{Entry station}
      \end{umlcall}
      \begin{umlcall}[op=RReq,return=success]{Entry station}{Dst station}
      \end{umlcall}
      \begin{umlcallself}[op=lookup,return=pkt-info]{Dst station} 
      \end{umlcallself}
      \begin{umlcall}[op=RRes,return=success]{Dst station}{Entry station}
      \end{umlcall}
      \begin{umlcall}[op=RRes,return=success]{Entry station}{Proxy}
      \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlcall}

    \begin{umlfragment}[type=loop, label=$\forall p_k$, inner ysep=1]
      \begin{umlcall}[dt=7, op=retrieve(token $p_k$),return=fragment $p_k$]{User}{Proxy}
        % redefine \CreateTxt to be empty
        \renewcommand\CreateTxt{}
        \umlcreatecall[x=7]{Proxy}{Station}
        \begin{umlcall}[op=RRes,return=success]{Proxy}{Station}
        \end{umlcall}
      \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlfragment}

    \begin{umlcallself}[dt=5, op=aggregate($p_k$), return=packet $p$]{User} 
    \end{umlcallself}
  \end{umlseqdiag} 

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is that what you meant by the way?